# Angularjs jquery plugin keeps adding dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using [this](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) jQuery plugin in an angular directive (below).  The problem I'm having is that it seems to always be re-initializing the plugin and adding new dom elements related to the plugin, instead of re-using the already existing ones.

Here's the directive I have:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('dateSelector', [function () {
  'use strict';

  return {
    link: function ($scope, elm, attrs) {

      $scope.query = $scope.query || {};
      $scope.query = {
          start: moment().subtract('days', 29).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        , end: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }
      elm.find('span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

      elm.daterangepicker({
          ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
          },
          startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
          endDate: moment()
        },
        function(start, end) {
          elm.find('span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
          $scope.query = {
              start: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            , end: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
          }
          if (angular.isFunction($scope.dateUpdate)) $scope.dateUpdate(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });

    }

  };

}]);
```

Any ideas how to get it so it will reuse the same `elm` ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you don't want the plugin to add <div class="daterangepicker">...</div> - the element that holds the calendar and other picking elements?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this ?

Comment: @j.wittwer, right - well I think it needs to create it once.  But in this case when I change routes, it doesn't destroy the old one and new ones are created, so I end up with a bunch of `<div class="daterangepicker"...`